# Order SQL Data Alphabetically in a PHP made HTML table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a directory of company folders, and each folder is named according to a company abbreviation. I am using `php` to make a table which creates a `checkbox`, a `href` to the directory, and then the company name (which it pulls from `SQL`).

Is there a way to alphabetically order the table based on the full company name pulled from `SQL` rather than the name of the folder. For example, in my image, 'United Stationers' would be below the other two alphabetically, but it isn't because the folder name comes first alphabetically.

[image: The Table]

Here's my `PHP` code:

```
$dir = "/var/files/companies/";
$myDirectory = opendir($dir);

$blacklist = array("Review");

while(false !== ($entryName = readdir($myDirectory))) {
    if (!in_array($entryName, $blacklist)) {
        $dirArray[] = $entryName;}}

closedir($myDirectory);
sort($dirArray);
$indexCount = count($dirArray);

//new array here for matching short/long names
$longNames=array();

$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket)
or die ('Could not connect to the database server' . mysqli_connect_error());

$query = "Select comp_id, short_name FROM database where vid=2";

if ($stmt = $con->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($comp_id, $short_name);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $longNames[strtolower($comp_id)]=$short_name;}
    $stmt->close();}

echo ("<TABLE border=1 cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0 class= whitelinks>\n");
echo ("<TR><TH>Manufacturer's Name</TH></TR>\n");

for ($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
    if (substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != ".") {
        echo("<td>");
        echo("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"comp[]\" value= '$dirArray[$index]' </a>");
        echo(" ");
        echo("<a href='/master/$dirArray[$index]'\>$dirArray[$index]</a>");
        echo("- ");
        if (array_key_exists($dirArray[$index], $longNames)){
            $short = ($longNames[$dirArray[$index]]);
            echo($short); }
        echo("</td>");
        echo("</TR>\n");}}

echo("</TABLE>\n");
```

Comment: so add an `order by ...` clause to your query...

Comment: @MarcB Thanks! I tried that, but that doesn't work because it's producing the company name only after it matches it to the corresponding company folder. So order that it's imported as doesn't really matter

Comment: where does this long name come from? You never fetch a `long_name`. you just select short_name, and stuff it into an array called "long_name".

Comment: @MarcB I make an array with keys called `longNames'. The key is the the `$comp_id` (which is equivalent to the folder names in the directory) and the value is `$short_name` (which is the full company name). As it makes the table, it prints the full company name (the value) when it inserts the key (the company abbreviation). `if (array_key_exists($dirArray[$index], $longNames)){
            $short = ($longNames[$dirArray[$index]]);
            echo($short); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the dirArray using a callback function once $longNames array is populated. Add this before your for loop:

```
usort($dirArray, function($dir1, $dir2) use ($longNames) {
    $name1 = isset($longNames[$dir1]) ? $longNames[$dir1] : $dir1;
    $name2 = isset($longNames[$dir2]) ? $longNames[$dir2] : $dir2;

    return strcmp($name1, $name2);
});
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php for more info about usort function.

EDIT: fixed syntax errors in code.

Answer (score 0):

I think change your query into this

$query = "Select comp_id, short_name FROM database where vid=2 order by short_name";

Comment: Thanks! I've tried this, but it doesn't work because the full company name is produced only after it is matched to the corresponding company folder. So the order that it's imported as doesn't matter. Like is there a way to organize after all the companies have been produced and matched?